# No responsive resizing of images ? Don't understand where's the problem

Tags: html, css

I'm rescaling the page but images just having the same size. What's the correct way ?

html:

```
               <div class="hello-page-top-menu">
               <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="../Maket1/assets/img/Logo.svg" alt="shopno"></a>
               <img class="burger-menu" src="./assets/img/Burger-Menu.svg">
               </div>
```

CSS:

```
.hello-page-top-menu  {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.hello-page-top-menu img.logo {
cursor: default;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.hello-page-top-menu .burger-menu {
cursor: default;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi, your images are scaling with the width of the window. see here: https://jsfiddle.net/ukwhn8p1/1/  Did you want them both to scale at the same time?

Comment: Yes, at the same time. I was testing in google chrome’s inspect window and the sizes didn’t scale while I was resizing the window. But thank you for your comment